# Should I send my AP scores from highschool to a graduate school I am applying to?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, cv, statistics, psychology

I scored a 3 on my Statistics test, and while it did not count for my undergraduate school as they only accept 4+, it would be a bonus when applying for a doctoral program in Clinical Psychology. However, since it was high school, would it do more harm than good?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that it would have any effect at all. You might be better to stress other, more recent things. Presumably your transcripts show proficiency in statistics sufficient for entry.

I doubt it would do harm other than to have someone, possibly, question why you did that. And a 3 isn't a huge benefit, as your undergrad experience showed.

However, if that is your *only* CV possibility pointing to knowing statistics, it would be a different matter.

Comment: @Anon: My gut reaction is that a 3 is sufficiently unimpressive to be detrimental. I wonder if it would be better to simply mention in one of the explanatory documents (letter of introduction, research interests, etc.) that beginning statistics was not taken as an undergraduate because AP statistics was taken in high school, and say nothing about the score or whether college credit was awarded. It seems to me that this is sufficiently distant in the past that the absence of additional details would seem perfectly reasonable and not raise any red flags.